# How to find the number of outcomes in an events with colored balls

Tags: probability

An urn holds 13 identical balls except that 1 is white, 9 are black, and 3 are red. An experiment consists of selecting two balls in succession without replacement and observing the color of each of the balls.

What math would I do to find the number of outcomes?

What math would I do to find the out the event if a certain color is not selected?

I couldn't find anything relating to this. I have found basic examples of how to find the number of out comes, however nothing like this. If you found something similar, please tell me.

Comment: For your second question, look up "hypergeometric distribution" and imagine your balls being identified as "certain color" and "not certain color" instead of 3 separate colors. For your first question, it sounds like you just need to list the possible color combinations you can get by picking out 3 balls, which doesn't need any special math.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "outcome".  Does order matter?  That is, is the draw $WB$ the same as $BW$?

Answer (score 1):

The number of outcomes can be calculated by the number of balls.
The first ball is one of 13, the second is one of 12, so the number of outcomes is $13\times 12$.

To calculate the probability that a colour is not selected, work out $1 -
\Pr(A)$, where A = outcome includes that colour.

Comment: Actually, it is easier to count outcomes that *don't* include that colour.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Even if the colour is white from the given question?

Comment: Yes, it is still *slightly* easier (although the effort approaches negligible either way).